# How to use caching with Django? (Preferably in GAE)

Tags: django, google-app-engine, memcached

I cannot make memcached work with GAE.
When I use Google cache backend, following the tutorial on [GAE website](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/memcache/usingmemcache), the views are not cached. So I used caching the urls as suggested in Django tutorial (e.g:

```
`(r'^example$', cache_page(60*15)(views.example)),
```

then I get this:

```
File "/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/third_party/django-1.4/django/middleware/cache.py", line 205, in __init__
self.cache_timeout = self.cache.default_timeout

 AttributeError: 'Client' object has no attribute 'default_timeout'
```

AttributeError: 'Client' object has no attribute 'default_timeout', if I use google backend (`django.core.cache.backends.memcached.MemcachedCache`) I get

```
Error: ImproperlyConfigured: Error importing middleware django.contrib.sessions.middleware: "No module named memcache".
```

Here somebody asked previously about using Django caching backend and suggest to install python-memcached, I did that and it still does not work.

Somebody suggested to write backend for GAE. I could not quite understand. If the best response to this question will be explaining step by step how to write a backend very roughly, then I will accept that answer.

Comment: I think that you will find your answers in here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1138715/will-djangos-cache-modules-work-on-google-app-engine

Comment: thanks, well I went those answers many times before posting this question above. But it is really confusing as two best voted answers contradict themselves, and also it is an old discussion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not all Django's functional works on App Engine. So, the functional you trying to use is inadmissible for App Engine Django library because of App Engine infrastructure restricts.

If I understand you correctly, you want to cache a whole page or in other words whole View's response? You can do this in that way (*just example*):

```
# Django on App Engine view example
from google.appengine.api import memcache
from django.http import HttpResponse

def cached_index_page(request):
  output_html = memcache.get('index_page')  # here we "take" from cache
  if output is not None:
    pass
  else:
    output_html = get_page_content()
    memcache.add('index_page', output_html, 60)  # here we "put" to cache" (timeout also here)
  HttpResponse(output_html)
```

For your purpose you may create Django's Middleware with auto caching any page you need.

Also make sure you removed all unrelated/not acceptable on App Engine stuff from configuration file.
Considering help page (https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/django), the minimal config looks like:

```
import os

# 'project' refers to the name of the module created with django-admin.py
ROOT_URLCONF = 'project.urls'

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
#    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
#    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.doc.XViewMiddleware',
    'google.appengine.ext.ndb.django_middleware.NdbDjangoMiddleware', # NoSQL db middleware
)

INSTALLED_APPS = (
#    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
#    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
)

ROOT_PATH = os.path.dirname(__file__)
TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    # Put strings here, like "/home/html/django_templates" or
    # "C:/www/django/templates".  Always use forward slashes, even on Windows.
    # Don't forget to use absolute paths, not relative paths.
    ROOT_PATH + '/templates',
)
```

Remember, that App Engine has own native caching, e.g. The Python runtime environment caches imported modules between requests on a single web server and you can tell App Engine to cache the CGI handler script itself, in addition to imported modules.

Helpful links:
https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/django-nonrelhttps://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/libraries27

Answer (score 0):

IMHO adding yet another question on this doesn't make this any less confusing.. [Django-nonrel ≤1.3 and Memcache on Google App Engine](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4010950/383793) might have an answer to your question.